# Generating .svelte component dynamically without using <svelte:component/>

Tags: svelte

##### Problem

I'm trying to generate svelte component dynamically in a .ts file. Thus, I'm not able to use `<svelte:component>` element as it can only be used inside .svelte files; in the HTML section. Is it possible to create some kind of svelte component renderer helper function?

##### Looking for solution

I'd need a logic for function of type: `(component: SvelteComponent, props: any) => HTMLElement`

##### Context

I figure rendering components like this might go around most (or maybe even every) intended coding patterns by Svelte, yet it would be a clean solution for what I'm trying to do. Specifically - I'm trying to inject content in [Full calendar as it's described here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event can return a DOM node array and you can render any component to DOM nodes directly using the [client-side component API](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api), so e.g.:

```js
eventContent() {
  const content = document.createElement('div');

  new Component({ target: content, props: ... });

  return { domNodes: [content] }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that the gist of it, works perfectly, thank you H.B.! I'll update my question with an answer of expanded logic so it could be used as a helper function ✌️

Answer (score 2):

Following up on H.B. answer, the code could be extracted into a helper function with corrent TS typing like so:

```js
import type {ComponentType} from "svelte";

export const componentToDom = (componentClass: ComponentType, props: object): HTMLElement => {
    const target = document.createElement('div')

    new componentClass({target, props})

    return target
}
```

---

And then inside Full calendar config:

```js
eventContent: () => ({domNodes: [componentToDom(MySvelteComponent, {})]})
```

Comment: Regarding types, `svelte` exports `ComponentType` which gives you the constructor signature, btw.

Comment: H.B., Legend 